# How to keep app.js file small

Tags: node.js

I am working on node js. Day by day my app.js file is being longer. How can I reduce it. So that I can write code in other files. Still I have tried nothing but read about modules on google.

Comment: How did you go with this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example might go as follows, in your app.js file you set up your server:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

const router = require('./router'); // <= get your router here


// Call the router, now you are listening 
// using the routes you have set up in the other file
router(app);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port: ', port);
});
```

And in your router you export the app function using module.exports

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.end('hello');
  }
  // all your routes here
}
```

Now you have separated out the logic of routing.

You can also export multiple methods or variables with the same process.

myFuncs.js

```
func1 function() {}
func2 function() {}

module.exports = {
  func1
  func2
}
```

(note here I am using ES6 it is the same as `module.exports = { func1: func1, func2: func2 }`

and then require them in the same way

```
const myFuncs = require('./myFuncs')

myFuncs.func1() // <= call func1
myFuncs.func2() // <= call func2
```

You can do the same operation with variables, and even combine with module.exports to shorten your code

mySecrets.js

```
module.exports = {secret_key: 'verysecretkey'}
```

app.js

```
const secret = require('./mySecrets')
```

That way you can keep your api_keys etc.. in a separate file, or even just variables that you want to import as required.

There are more details available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the code into different files and then use `require` to import them to `app.js`

```
var init = require('./config/init')(), 
config = require('./config/config')
```

In the above code I have separated out some init function and config files to a separate files and I am importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a module within an external file e.g.: `./hello.js`:

```
module.exports = {
     function1 : function(){console.log('hello module');}
};
```

Load that module within your `app.js`:

```
var hello = require('./hello.js');

// call your function
hello.function1();
```